# Airflow Deferrable Operator Pattern for Event-driven DAGs

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm looking for examples of patterns in place for event-driven DAGs, specifically those with dependencies on other DAGs. Let's start with a simple example:

```
dag_a -> dag_b
```

`dag_b` depends on `dag_a`. I understand that at the end of `dag_a` I can add a trigger to launch `dag_b`. However, this philosophically feels misaligned from an abstraction standpoint: `dag_a` does not need to understand or know that `dag_b` exists, yet this pattern would enforce the responsibility of calling `dag_b` on `dag_a`.

Let's consider a slightly more complex example (pardon my poor ASCII drawing skills):

```
dag_a ------> dag_c
         /
dag_b --/
```

In this case, if `dag_c` depends on both `dag_a` and `dag_b`. I understand that we could set up a sensor for the output of each `dag_a` and `dag_b`, but with the advent of deferrable operators, it doesn't seem that this remains a best practice. I suppose I'm wondering how to set up a DAG of DAGs in an async fashion.

The potential for deferrable operators for event-driven DAGs is introduced in Astronomer's guide here: https://www.astronomer.io/guides/deferrable-operators, but it's unclear how it would be best applied these in light of the above examples.

More concretely, I'm envisioning a use case where multiple DAGs run every day (so they share the same run date), and the output of each DAG is a date partition in a table somewhere. Downstream DAGs consume the partitions of the upstream tables, so we want to schedule them such that downstream DAGs don't attempt to run before the upstream ones complete.

Right now I'm using a "fail fast and often" approach in downstream dags, where they start running at the scheduled date, but first check if the data they need exists upstream, and if not the task fails. I have these tasks set to retry every x interval, with high number of retries (e.g. retry every hour for 24 hours, if it's still not there then something is wrong and the DAG fails). This is fine since 1) it works for the most part and 2) I don't believe the failed tasks continue to occupy a worker slot between retries, so it actually is somewhat async (I could be wrong). It's just a little crude, so I'm imagining there is a better way.

Any tactical advice for how to set this relationship up to be more event driven while still benefitting from the async nature of deferrable operators is welcome.

Comment: Any chance you could share your findings on this topic?

Comment: @orak I wasn't able to find any decent best practices practices here for a fully event-driven system. It may be possible to hack something together but it seems as though this may be a little outside of Airflow's paradigm.

The best alternative I was able to come up with was just to use deferrable operators to sense the output of upstream dags. It's not perfect, but it works well enough.

Answer (score 1):

we are using an event bus to connect the DAGs, the end task of a DAG will send the event out, and followed DAG will be triggered in the orchestrator according to the event type.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Airflow 2.4 you can use [data-aware scheduling](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/datasets.html). It would look like this:

```
dag_a_finished = Dataset("dag_a_finished")

with DAG(dag_id="dag_a", ...):
    # Last task in dag_a
    BashOperator(task_id="final", outlets=[dag_a_finished], ...)

with DAG(dag_id="dag_b", schedule=[dag_a_finished], ...):
    ...

with DAG(dag_id="dag_c", schedule=[dag_a_finished], ...):
    ...
```

In theory Dataset should represent some piece of data, but technically nothing prevents you from making it just a string identifier used for setting up DAG dependency - just like in above example.